# How to flush the data cache of RISCV rocket chip?

Tags: riscv

I would like to flush dedicated cache lines or the whole data cache of the RISCV Rocket Chip implementation.
Is there a special ISA command to achieve this, like CFLUSH (x86) or writing to the CP15 co-processor (ARM)?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not a way to flush the data caches on Rocket. It does support uncached memory operations and the cache is physically addressed and fully cache coherent.